# What can I use for Android Developement

Tags: java, c#, android

Hello I'm an informatics apprentice and already learned to program a bit.

In my first year we developed an Android App with Android Studio (Java) and I was thinking this is the only way to create an Android App but then I saw someone creating a game with  Unity (C#).

Now I'm wondering if these 2 options are the only 2 or are there more? And if yes which ones?

Comment: you can write android apps using notepad/a text editor and compile it using a android compiler. There are many IDEs out there, just google it.

Comment: you can create Android Apps on Google chrome too. Just try typing your question title in the search bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend sticking to Android Studio to learn coding in Android. This is due to three reasons:

1. Android Studio is officially supported by Android, which means they have more documentation and project examples that follow the Android Studio project structure.
2. Android Studio is good development IDE for both beginners and experts alike.
3. Android Studio is a PITA to get set up for total beginners, but the learning experience goes a long way.

If you want another platform, better try something like MIT App Inventor (You won't learn much with this) or Xamarin.

Xamarin is also another highly recommended platform that you might want to learn. The main advantage is that it is cross-platform, which will let you code apps for multiple mobile platforms at once.